Enforcing a Prediction Language for NLLB Machine Translation Model
All I need is a way to insert my GenerationConfig into the HuggingFace Seq2Seq Trainer.
I want to enforce facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M model's predictions to be in Arabic, I am using transformers library.
Here is my Trainer Code
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer

wandb.init(project="project_name")

# https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.18.0/en/performance
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="filename",
    save_total_limit=1,
    
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=16 // 2,
    # gradient_checkpointing=True,
    
    weight_decay=0.01,
    warmup_steps=1_000,
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
    
    
    num_train_epochs=4,
    
    predict_with_generate=True,
    fp16=True,
    push_to_hub=True,
    report_to='wandb'
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)


I tried doing this
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

model.config.forced_bos_token_id = tokenizer.lang_code_to_id["arb_Arab"]

And it works, In Sanity Checking at least. But when i started the training loop, I got this:
warnings.warn(
Some non-default generation parameters are set in the model config. These should go into a GenerationConfig file (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#save-a-custom-decoding-strategy-with-your-model) instead. This warning will be raised to an exception in v4.41.
Non-default generation parameters: {'max_length': 200, 'forced_bos_token_id': 256011}
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py:429: UserWarning: torch.utils.checkpoint: please pass in use_reentrant=True or use_reentrant=False explicitly. The default value of use_reentrant will be updated to be False in the future. To maintain current behavior, pass use_reentrant=True. It is recommended that you use use_reentrant=False. Refer to docs for more details on the differences between the two variants.

and my eval loss is NaN for some reason. All I need is a way to insert my GenerationConfig into the Trainer.
